# Get value of 'cell' in one dataframe based on another dataframe using pandas conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Given DF1:

```
Title   |   Origin    |  %
Analyst   Referral       3
Analyst   University    10
Manager   University     1
```

and DF2:

```
Title   |   Referral   |  University
Analyst        
Manager
```

I'm trying set the values inside DF2 based on conditions such as:

```
DF2['Referral'] = np.where((DF1['Title']=='Analyst') & (DF1['Origin']=='Referral')), DF1['%'], '0'
```

What I'm getting as a result, is all the values in `DF1['%']`, and Im expecting to get only the value in the row where the conditions are met.

Like this:

```
Title   |   Referral   |  University
Analyst        3             10
Manager                       1
```

Also, there is probably a more efficient way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: `df.pivot('title', 'Origin', '&')`?

Comment: Bless your soul!

That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use pivot, no need for logic:

```
s = """Title|Origin|%
Analyst|Referral|3
Analyst|University|10
Manager|University|1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|')

df.pivot('Title', 'Origin', '%')

Origin   Referral  University
Title                        
Analyst       3.0        10.0
Manager       NaN         1.0
```